# VB.Net: Dynamically Select Image from My.Resources

Tags: .net, vb.net, image, controls, my.resources

I have a group of images in my My.Resources.  I want to select select images to display dynamically at run time.  How do I do this?

```
'Static (Compile time) Assignment
UltraPictureBox1.Image = my.Resources.zoo_picture_1

'Dynamic (Runtime) Assignment
UltraPictureBox1.Image = ???
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
UltraPictureBox1.Image = _
    My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(object_name_as_string)
```

Comment: Oh man they could have made the same code work in both situations! I mean, .NET is full of those things like "do not say it's "form1", call it "me" instead". They could simply have auto-correction or even better, compile the code in the same way. /rant

Answer (score 14):

This works for me at runtime too:

```
UltraPictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.MyPicture
```

No strings involved and if I change the name it is automatically updated by refactoring.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you don't include extension of the resource, nor path to it. It's only the resource file name.

```
PictureBoxName.Image = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("object_name")
```

Comment: How would I differ between File.jpg and File.pdf, if I have these resources (same filename, different extension)?

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim resources As Object = My.Resources.ResourceManager
PictureBoxName.Image = resources.GetObject("Company_Logo")
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you must change the name (or check to get it automatically from compiler).

Example:

Filename = `amp2-rot.png`

It is not working as:

```
PictureBoxName.Image = resources.GetObject("amp2-rot.png")
```

It works, just as `amp2_rot` for me:

```
 PictureBox_L1.Image = My.Resources.Resource.amp2_rot
```